# How to redirect user to a specific page in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm learning up about ACL and Auth in cakePHP, but i need redirect the user to a panel home that show basic informations (like a resume of all system), currently the system redirect the user to `posts/add`. I don't know how to redirect to a home page and show data of all Models.

My code is based (and working) in:

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html

Comment: In what situation(s) do you want to redirect to this page? Do you have the page working if you enter the URL manually?

Comment: Not. When the user log into system i need redirect to a page like /panel and in that show data of all Models. Currently i need make a Controller and Model to make a View.

Comment: You need to make a controller, yes. It doesn't need to have a model. It's not clear whether your problem is that you don't know how to redirect after login, or how to build the page you want to redirect to, or both.

Comment: Really your comment helped me as a lot. I just made a Controller called Panel, thank you. I didn't know that Model is optional. Thank you.